# Amazon RDS stuck with Rebooting Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have tried to reboot the Amazon RDS and the status is stuck at Rebooting. It's been 3 days now and it still shows the same message. I have tried killing all the processes running on the database but it did not work.

I'm unable to take a snapshot also due to this.

Please suggest a solution.

Image for Reference

[image: Image for Reference]

Answer (score 2):

Contact AWS support.

Realistically that is the only way you will get this resolved.  3 days implies something has gone wrong with the underlying system and they will need to get system engineers involved to resolve it.